# Como transformar letras maiúsculas em minúsculas e minúsculas em maiúsculas no Python?

Tags: python, string

Qual era o nome do método em Python que transforma letras maiúsculas em minúsculas e minúsculas em maiúsculas na mesma string?

Por exemplo:

```
texto = "AquI TeM umA StrinG"
saída = "aQUi tEm UMa sTRINg"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
texto.swapcase()
#'aQUi tEm UMa sTRINg'
```

Comment: Eu lembro que tinha esse método, só que agora me faltou na memória.

Comment: @AlexFeliciano se a resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como 'aceita'!

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou mesmo. Eu sabia que existia essa função rsrsrs.

Answer (score 7):

Acredito que não tenha uma função específica para isso. Mas como boa linguagem que se preze, ela possui duas funções para trabalhar com este tipo de problema.

A primeira função é a `.upper()` que retorna o caractere em maiúsculo e a segunda é `.lower()` que faz o inverso. Elas tecnicamente não tratam o caractere para ignorar ou reverter o estado, mas temos outras funções que fazem a verificação.

Para verificar se um caractere já está maiúsculo, basta usarmos a função `.isupper()` e o inverso `.islower()`.

## Então, como podemos implementar isso?

Vamos criar a função `reverter_string` que toma como argumento uma string, ela deve retornar o "inverso da string" (no quesito maiúsculas). Basicamente, vamos iterar cada caractere verificando se ele está maiúsculo, caso esteja, vamos torná-lo minúsculo, e vice-versa.

O algoritmo aplicado é esse:

```py
def reverter(string):
   retorno = ''
   for caractere in string:
      if caractere.isupper():
         retorno += caractere.lower()
      else:
         retorno += caractere.upper()
   return retorno
```

Este é basicamente o código. A questão é: o código está muito grande! Neste caso, podemos usar uma função muito útil do Python (que também deve haver em algumas muitas linguagens), a função `map()`. Essa função mapeia cada item de um objeto que possa ser iterado (como strings, tuplas, listas, dicionários) e retorna um resultado final realizando uma função em cada um.

Neste caso, a função reverter string se tornara apenas isso:

```py
def reverter(string):
   return ''.join(map(lambda c: c.upper() if c.islower() else c.lower(), string))
```

**O código ainda ficou confuso?**

A função `map` toma uma função e um string, e analisa cada caractere usando a função do primeiro argumento (que usa o mesmo algoritmo que a função anterior), e retorna um *map object*, que se assemelha a um iterator.

O que isso quer dizer?

Quer dizer que eu preciso juntar os caracteres com um `join`, por isso ele ali presente. Do contrário terei uma lista, ao invés de uma string no retorno.

**É isso...**

**EDIT:**

Há uma função específica para isso, chamada `.swapcase()`. Simplesmente aplique:

```py
string = "python É uma LINGUAGEM mágica"
string.swapcase()
# retorna: 'PYTHON é UMA linguagem MÁGICA'
```

Comment: Depois que respondi fui ler na documentação oficial do Python, e realmente há uma função. Existe a função `.swapcase()`, podendo ser encontrada nesse link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase

Answer (score 6):

O método que você procura é [`swapcase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase). Apenas complementando as outras respostas, a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) menciona que nem sempre `s.swapcase().swapcase() == s`. Ou seja, se você inverter as maiúsculas e minúsculas, e depois fazer esta operação de novo, o resultado nem sempre será a string original.

Um exemplo em que isso acontece:

```py
s = "ς"
print(s.swapcase())
print(s.swapcase().swapcase())
```

A saída é:

```
Σ
σ
```

Isso acontece porque tanto o [caractere `ς`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03c2/index.htm) (GREEK SMALL LETTER FINAL SIGMA) quanto o [caractere `σ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03c3/index.htm) (GREEK SMALL LETTER SIGMA) são usados para representar a letra *sigma* minúscula (se não me engano a primeira só é usada no final de uma palavra, mas como não sou fluente em grego, então podem haver mais regras envolvidas).

Para ambas, a sua versão maiúscula é o [caractere `Σ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a3/index.htm) (GREEK CAPITAL LETTER SIGMA), então o primeiro `swapcase()` resulta em `Σ`. Mas ao fazer o segundo `swapcase`, o resultado é `σ`.

Curiosamente, caso tenha mais de um caractere (formando uma palavra), a situação acima não acontece:

```py
s = "πς"
print(s.swapcase())
print(s.swapcase().swapcase())
```

A saída é:

```
ΠΣ
πς
```

Quando o caractere `ς` não está sozinho, as duas chamadas de `swapcase` resultam no caractere original. Provavelmente porque agora ele está no final de uma palavra (mas não sei porque o comportamento é diferente quando ele está sozinho). E obviamente eu nem sei se a string acima é uma palavra válida em grego (*eu chutaria que não*). De qualquer forma, isso mostra como os conceitos de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas nem sempre é algo tão óbvio, e conhecer o idioma em que as strings estão ajuda bastante quando for lidar com as mesmas.

---

Outro exemplo é o [caractere alemão `ß`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm), que [quando convertido para maiúscula, se transforma em "SS"](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/25/473632.html). E ao converter de volta para minúscula, o "SS" se transforma em "ss":

```py
s = "ßabc"
print(s.swapcase())
print(s.swapcase().swapcase())
```

Saída:

```
SSABC
ssabc
```

---

Evidentemente que se você só vai trabalhar com textos em português (ou qualquer idioma que só use o alfabeto latino), esses problemas não ocorrerão. Mas é interessante saber que esse tipo de coisa pode acontecer, dependendo do caso.

[Esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24134091) possui uma lista mais completa dos caracteres com os quais esse tipo de situação ocorre.

Comment: Obrigado pela complementação.